# USB and PCI devices taking a LOT of power

Tags: power-management, battery

So I ran `powertop` on my laptop and saw that I have a lot of devices that are draining power on full speed the whole time according to the program.

[image: powertop]

As you can see there a lot of things taking 100% and my battery drainage is very high because of that.

Is there a way to fix this problem somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for;

http://www.linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html

TLP is a power management tool for Linux. It brings you the benefits of advanced power management without the need to understand every technical detail.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp
```

Run PowerTOP before & after to see difference. Power settings will be re-profiled by TLP upon fresh boot.